# What library does ObjectContext come from in VB5?

Tags: objectcontext, vb5

First of all, let me myself make the obligatory snarky comment about having to maintain VB5 code: yes, it's pitiful, but can we please just cut to the chase?  Thanks.

I am having to revisit some VERY old code that was written in 1998 and which hasn't been touched since 2003.  The problem I am having is that I am getting a compile error on this:

```
Dim ObjCtx As ObjectContext
```

The VB5 compiler throws a compile error: User-defined type not defined

This is not of course a user-defined type, but is a part of some libary or another.  My problem is that I don't know which library I might be missing.  The workstation is reconstructed from an old Windows 2000 workstation, and not all libraries may have been installed.  I am suspecting that ObjectContext might be a part of some version of ADO (ActiveX Data Objects), of which only v2.1 is currently installed.

Are there any old-timers out there who remember anything about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a reference to your project for "COM+ Services Type Library" (COMSVCS.DLL)